# Inner Join Returning No Results MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, sql-server-2014

I have two tables containing geographical data.
I want to inner join table1 to table2 to get all of table1 but with an extra field from table2.
When I tried the following:

```
select a.*, b.field from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on (cast(a.Latitude as float) = cast(b.Latitude as float))
and (cast(a.Longitude as float) = cast(b.Longitude as float))
```

I was met with no results, but have checked that there are the same exact pairs
of lat longs in both tables.

As a check, I joined by just latitudes, then by just longitudes and had results, so it  seems to be a problem with having both latitudes and longitudes joined.

Comment: Why are you casting as float?

Comment: I tried casting to avoid datatype errors, but no have realised its unnecessary. Problem still occurs without cast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining on floating point numbers is simply the wrong thing to do.  It would be nice if the SQL parse returned a warning when one attempts to do this.  The problem is that floating point numbers can look the same, but really be different in the last bit.

First, try using the native types (which should be decimal or character):

```
select a.*, b.field
from table1 a inner join
     table2 b
     on a.Latitude  = b.Latitude and
        a.Longitude = b.Longitude ;
```

If that doesn't work, you can use logic like this:

```
select a.*, b.field
from table1 a inner join
     table2 b
     on a.Latitude between b.Latitude - 0.0001 and b.Latitude + 0.0001 and
        a.Longitude between b.Longitude - 0.0001 and b.Longitude + 0.0001;
```

The `0.0001` is an arbitrary threshold for identifying values as being the same when they are slightly different.  I'm not sure what the right value is.  However, this corresponds to about 36 feet (11 meters) at most, so it seems like a reasonable precision.

The moral of the story is that lats and longs should be stored using fixed-length decimal precision or using representations in GIS packages.

Comment: What is the reason for +-+  0.0001 ?

Comment: I tried their native types but received no results still, but thank you for your second suggestion! I've done it to ±0.0000001 for lat longs to be sure they're being joined to exactly the right ones (I have a lot of very close GPS points) and the join seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, b.field from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on (a.Latitude = b.Latitude and a.Longitude = b.Longitude)
```

You don't need a cast since both are Latitude and will be of the same data type.